# Python read data from API, typeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, api, url

Im new in python. I try read some data from api, but have problem in second url, i dont know how parse api when i have more data. First URL have only one "NAME", second have more NAMES....
How can i print all names from second url...
Thankyou...

```
import os
from urllib import urlopen
import json

url = urlopen('https://www.coincalculators.io/api.aspx?name=ethereum&hashrate=420000000&power=0&poolfee=1&powercost=0&difficultytime=0').read()
data= json.loads(url)  
name = data["name"] # OK
print name
rewardsInMonth = data["rewardsInMonth"] # OK
print rewardsInMonth
#url with more names
url2 = urlopen('https://www.coincalculators.io/api/allcoins.aspx?hashrate=420000000&power=0&powercost=0&difficultytime=0&algorithm=Ethash').read()
data2= json.loads(url2)  
name2 = data2["name"] # OK
print name2
```

I see have one square bracket in second url and here is problem for me.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Different endpoints of this API return different data structures. The first call returns just one dict, the second one (to the `allcoins.aspx` endpoint) not surprisingly a list of dicts.

Nudging you very politely into the direction of Python 3 and the `requests` module,  the second URL returns a list, so you can use the `for` loop to iterate over the coins:

```
import requests

coin = requests.get("https://www.coincalculators.io/api.aspx?name=ethereum&hashrate=420000000&power=0&poolfee=1&powercost=0&difficultytime=0").json()
print(coin["name"])

for coin in requests.get("https://www.coincalculators.io/api/allcoins.aspx?hashrate=420000000&power=0&powercost=0&difficultytime=0&algorithm=Ethash").json():
    print(coin["name"])
```

Comment: ThankYou!  Now work- i see print all "names". Now i have second problem. All "names" (Coins) have own "profitInDayUSD". And i must convert all profit of coins to float..... "Name" = float"profitInDayUSD" ...then I have to insert IF function ( If some coins have bigger "profitInDayUSD" then "2 USD ", set Output to ON ( Rassberry Pi), switch relay to ON, PC start mining :)    I have a lot of work.... :)

Comment: `if float(coin["profitInDayUSD"]) > 2.0: start_mining(coin["name"])` :-)